# JS ограничение на количество генерируемых дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой штукой - у js(или у js в браузере) оказывается есть ограничение на количество генерируемых дочерних элементов.
Подскажите как обойти?

Воспроизведение моей проблемы: Нажимаем "Выполнить код", затем нажимаем на кнопку "новый тег внутри" больше 10 раз. Рамка рисуется только при первых 10 нажатиях, а больше не рисуется.

```js
(function(){
var i = 1;
document.querySelector('#raz8').onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = '<span style="border-color: rgba(255,0,0,'+i+');">'+this.innerHTML+'</span>';
  i = i - 0.1;
}
})()
```

```html
<style>
#raz8 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
<button type="button" id="raz8">новый тег внутри</button>
```

Этот пример мне показался короче, а моя проблема при рисовании строк таблицы - мне нужно чтобы их было больше 10, а больше 10 так же не рисуется. Таблицу генерю так: http://mainproject.ru/js/table.shtml , просто 15 этажным повторением js кода, поэтому здесь приводить такой код и постеснялся)

Пример с рамкой взят отсюда: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/08/appendchild-removechild-javascript.html
Спасибо!

Comment: Вполне полезный ответ. Я вот не знал. Так что выносите в ответ.

Comment: Да. Поменял 0.1 на 0.05 рисуется 20 видимых рамок - здесь все верно. Что в моем случае с таблицей пока что не понятно. Я думаю приложи я достаточно усилий чтобы 15 этажный код в функцию переписать мне бы и вопрос задавать не пришлось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это никакое не ограничение. Рамка рисуется каждый раз с прозрачностью `i - 0.1`.
Поскольку `i = 1`, то первый клик даст непрозрачную рамку, со 2-го раза - 0.9 и до 10-го клика становится 0.1, на 11-ый клик - прозрачность 0, поэтому не удивительно, что вы не видите обводку со 100%-ой прозрачностью.
А так и в 11-ый раз js работает и в 111-ый.